# Bootstrap & Angular loop

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a card with a title and several lines with my data for I'm using Bootstrap, but instead of putting the items on the line they are all on the same line how to do for who goes on the line at each item.

**expected**

```
    title
    item 1
    item 2
    item 3
```

**result**

```
 title
    item 1 item 2 item 3
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-3" *ngFor="let t of arrayT | keyvalue">
    <ul class="list-group">
     <li class="list-groupe-item">{{t.key}}</li>
     <li class="list-groupe-item">{{t.value}}</li>
   </ul>
   </div>     
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be replicating the col-3 div element

you need to move the for loop to ng-container
like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let t of arrayT">
                    <li class="list-group-item">{{t.key}} {{t.value}}</li>
                </ng-container>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help but it remains the same, the items are still on a single line

Comment: You may have custom css?

Comment: OK I got it 
There was a mistake of `time` instead of `item` for StPaulis 
& `groupe` instead of `group`

Comment: nothing moves everything stays in the same place i have no css i think the keyvalue pipe does that

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it as mfort suggested and replace the `list-groupe-item` with
`list-group-item`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let t of arrayT">
                    <li class="list-group-item">{{t.key}}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">{{t.value}}</li>
                </ng-container>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/

Comment: Where is `list-groupe-time` written ?

Comment: In the question and in your reply

Comment: I made the modification but nothing changes too weird

Comment: nothing changes is that pipe "keyvalue" to have something in it